# Inserting an array inside another array in C

Tags: arrays, c, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make an array variable that, inside each position, it has another array in it. My case is the following:

```
int main() {
    char foo[2];
    char dummy[3] = {'F', 'O', 'X'};

    foo[1] = dummy;
    printf("%c", foo[1]);
    /* This printf is like a way of saying "show me the 'dummy' list" */

    return 0;
}
```

With this code, i would expect the console to show me the dummy list. Instead, i got a warning that says:

> "warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
> 'char' from 'char [3]' [-Wint-
> conversion]"

I dont know if my problem is well understood, but i would like to get an array position like foo[1] to contain another array like dummy, so when i call foo[1] i get that dummy array.

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance for taking your time to help me.

Comment: `foo[1]` is one `char`, so it cannot contain array consists of multiple `char`s. Maybe you want `char* foo[2];` and `printf("%.3s", foo[1]);`?

Comment: To have arrays have another array as its elements, you can write like `char foo[2][3];` (now `foo` of 2-element array of "3-element array of `char`") The assignment will be `memcpy(foo[1], dummy, sizeof(dummy));` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The variable *foo* that you have defined is a character array of length two but what you want is an array of character pointers. Note that the character array *dummy* is non-terminated; it is better to leave out the length and initialize it with a string literal instead. Also, to print a string you need to use `%s` in the call to *printf*. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *foo[2];
    char dummy[] = "FOX";

    foo[1] = dummy;
    printf("%s\n", foo[1]);
    return 0;
}
```